# Como faço para a logo sumir quando rolar a página?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou criando um menu com a versão 4.1.3 do Bootstrap e gostaria de saber como posso fazer para ao rolar a página a logo desaparecer? No caso, só o menu deve ficar.

> Obs.: Ao voltar a posição inicial a logo deverá reaparecer.

O menu já está fixo

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img id="brand-image" alt="Website Logo" src="img/logo.png" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#brand-image {
  height: 100px;
  float: center;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 15px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Primeiro: qual a versão do bootstrap você está usando?

Comment: A última versão a 4.1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta resposta é apenas um complemento à [resposta do @hugocsl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/331248/6333).

Quando se fala de eventos como [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll), [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) ou [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove) é sempre importante lembrar que eles são lançados várias vezes por segundo enquanto o usuário interage com a página. Ou seja, dependendo do quê você faz dentro da função *handler* do evento, você pode deixar sua página lenta (ex.: acessar o DOM).

Se não há necessidade de executar esta função tão repetidamente você pode usar as técnicas [`debounce` e `throttle`](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/), que servem para limitar a execução de uma função em um período de tempo.

O [`debounce`](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/#article-header-id-0) vai esperar que o evento pare de ser lançado por X segundos antes de ativar a função *handler*.

O [`throttle`](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/#article-header-id-5) só vai permitir que a função *handler* seja executada a cada X segundos.

Exemplo:

```
// Só vai executar quando o usuário para de digitar por 1 segundo
$elemento.on('keyup', _.debounce(function() {
    console.log('debounce');
}, 1000));


// Enquanto o usuário seguir digitando, vai executar a cada segundo
$elemento.on('keyup', _.throttle(function() {
    console.log('throttle');
}, 1000));
```

---

Outra otimização, bem mais simples, é salvar o elemento DOM em uma variável para usar depois, visto que o acesso ao DOM é custoso em termos de performance.

Ao invés de:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // é executado cada vez que 'scroll' é lançado
    $("#brand-image").fadeOut();
});
```

É mais performático usar:

```
// É executado apenas uma vez
var $brandImage = $("#brand-image");

$(window).scroll(function() {
    // Usa a refêrencia salva anteriormente
    $brandImage.fadeOut();
});
```

E a última e menos impactante é que, quando você faz:

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

Você está convertendo um DOMElement em um objeto jQuery, não é tão custoso quanto acessar o DOM, mas ainda sim pode ser facilmente substituído pela propriedade [`window.pageYOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset) que é nativo e a compatibilidade é aceitável (IE 9+).

---

Abaixo segue o código do @hugocsl com o *handler* de eventos normal, com *debounce* e com *throttle* para ilustrar a importância destas técnicas.

PS: Nos exemplos estou usando os métodos [`_.debounce()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce) e [`_.throttle()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#throttle) da biblioteca [lodash](https://lodash.com/).

---

### Normal

```js
var $brandImage = $("#brand-image");
var $scrollHelper = $("#scroll-helper");
var count_scroll = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $scrollHelper.html("scroll triggered: " + ++count_scroll);
  if (this.pageYOffset >= 140) { // 140 é a distancia que vc rola antes da logo sumir
    $brandImage.fadeOut();
  } else {
    $brandImage.fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
#scroll-helper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img id="brand-image"src="https://placecage.com/50/50" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
</nav>

<div style="height:1000px; width: 100ps;"></div>
<span id="scroll-helper">scroll triggered: 0</span>
```

---

### Debounce

```js
var $brandImage = $("#brand-image");
var $scrollHelper = $("#scroll-helper");
var count_scroll = 0;

$(window).scroll(_.debounce(function() {
  $scrollHelper.html("scroll triggered: " + ++count_scroll);
  if (this.pageYOffset >= 140) { // 140 é a distancia que vc rola antes da logo sumir
    $brandImage.fadeOut();
  } else {
    $brandImage.fadeIn();
  }
}, 300));
```

```css
#scroll-helper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img id="brand-image"src="https://placecage.com/50/50" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
</nav>

<div style="height:1000px; width: 100ps;"></div>
<span id="scroll-helper">scroll triggered: 0</span>
```

---

### Throttle

```js
var $brandImage = $("#brand-image");
var $scrollHelper = $("#scroll-helper");
var count_scroll = 0;

$(window).scroll(_.throttle(function() {
  $scrollHelper.html("scroll triggered: " + ++count_scroll);
  if (this.pageYOffset >= 140) { // 140 é a distancia que vc rola antes da logo sumir
    $brandImage.fadeOut();
  } else {
    $brandImage.fadeIn();
  }
}, 300));
```

```css
#scroll-helper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img id="brand-image"src="https://placecage.com/50/50" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
</nav>

<div style="height:1000px; width: 100ps;"></div>
<span id="scroll-helper">scroll triggered: 0</span>
```

Comment: Cara essa resposta é tão interessante que merecia uma Pergunta só para ele rss. Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento!

Comment: Valeu! Que bom que ajudou!

Comment: Excelente resposta. :) +1

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro para para esse efeito ser válido seria interessante você deixar seu menu sempre fixo no topo da página. Para isso precisa usar a classe `.fixed-top` na *navbar* (veja na [documentação oficial](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement)).

Depois como um jQuery simples *(o jQuery já faz parte do Bootstrap então não tem problema usá-lo)* é possível fazer um `fadeOut` e `fadeIn` no evento *scroll*.

Para ver o resultado veja o exemplo abaixo. Deixei comentado o lugar onde você controla a "distância" do *scroll* antes da logo sumir.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 140) { // 140 é a distancia que vc rola antes da logo sumir
    $("#brand-image").fadeOut();
  } else {
    $("#brand-image").fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img id="brand-image" alt="Website Logo" src="https://placecage.com/50/50" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div style="height:1000px; width: 100ps;"></div>
```

Comment: não seria interessante ter uma pequena explicação de como fazer um *throttle* ou *debouce* do handler de evento? Pois se você colocar um `console.log` no handler de evento vai ver que a função executa muitas vezes e pode deixar a página lenta.

Comment: E deixar o `$("#brand-image")` fora do handler também, por motivos de perfomance.

Comment: @fernandosavio tem como fazer um *debounce* de forma simples?é só usar um `_.debounce` antes da function e no final colocar o valor do "intervalo"? Vou testar aqui... Eu não entendo muito de jQuery :)

Comment: Acho que a maneira mais fácil é usar o debounce do lodash. Assim o código segue curto e não foge muito do escopo da pergunta. Qualquer coisa eu faço um fiddle no início da tarde e comento aqui pra você analisar

Comment: @fernandosavio encontrei esse material, parece bem interessante! https://www.origamid.com/codex/diminuir-o-menu-fixo-ao-scroll/ `_.debounce`

Comment: É isso mesmo! Acho importante falar destas técnicas quando falamos sobre eventos que são repetidos muitas vezes por segundo como o scroll ou dragover

Comment: @fernandosavio sou poucos que tem essa preocupação é verdade... Eu mesmo não tenho conhecimento suficiente para usar essas técnicas nas minhas resposta. Mas vou dar uma estudada no assunto! Acho que a culpa do Chrome consumir tanta memória muitas vezes e pq o próprio dev que não otimizou o código... Mas ai é conversa pra Chat da STOF

Comment: Postei uma resposta como complemento. Vai ser bom deixar junto caso alguém caia aqui.

Answer (score 3):

1: Você não informou qual versão do `bootstrap` está usando.

2: Você não informou se já conseguiu deixar o menu fixo.

Com a ausência dessas informações, fiz um exemplo usando a versão `4.1`  do `bootstrap` .

> Note que eu acrescentei a classe `.sticky-top`no navbar para a mesma ficar fixa. Vale lembrar que essa classe usa uma position `sticky`, o que ainda  não é suportado no IE 11. Para acessar a lista completa dos navegadores que oferecem suporte, consulte [aqui](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).  Caso preferir, utilize a classe `fixed-top`.

Basicamente você precisará ficar `escultando` o evento de `scroll` e verificar quando o mesmo chegar em um determinado valor que você definir, após isso, você esconde e mostra a imagem conforme necessidade.

A variável `length` foi declarada para você testar com outros valores.

Recomendo tirar o comentário do `console.log()` para ver o funcionamento da captura do `scroll`.

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  let scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
  let length = 100;
  //console.log('scroll: '+ scroll);

  if (scroll > length) {
    $('#brand-image').hide();
  } else {
    $('#brand-image').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.main {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img id="brand-image" alt="Website Logo" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSgZ_2jtGVpp0G-t966PJgbdGVgJ71RFXH7_5syQEl3WNaPBUmr" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="main">
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```