# Como criar uma caixa de pesquisa dinâmica?

Tags: javascript, html, algoritmo-de-busca, teclado

Neste site - http://www.euescolhiesperar.com/ - quando você digita na caixa de pesquisa, os resultados aparecem instantaneamente sem ser necessário apertar enter. Como posso fazer isso no Blogger?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode ouvir o evento [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) do input e executar a pesquisa após isso.

Exemplo:

```js
var search = document.getElementById('search');
var log = document.getElementById('log');

/*
  - keyup é lançado a cada tecla pressionada no input
*/
search.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  // Cria um <li> e adiciona na <ul> apenas para exemplificar
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = "Pesquisando: " + this.value;
  log.insertBefore(li, log.firstChild);
});
```

```html
<input id="search">
<hr>
<ul id="log"></ul>
```

Por motivos de performance, você pode fazer um [debounce](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/#article-header-id-0) no evento para não realizar muitas pesquisas ao mesmo tempo ([exemplo de debounce e throttle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/331307/6333)).

No exemplo a seguir, estou usando a função [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce) da biblioteca [lodash](https://lodash.com/) por motivos de praticidade:

```js
var search = document.getElementById('search');
var log = document.getElementById('log');

/*
  - keyup é lançado a cada tecla pressionada no input
  - debounce faz com que a função só executa depois que
o usuário parar de digitar por 1 segundo
*/
search.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(function() {
  // Cria um <li> e adiciona na <ul> apenas para exemplificar
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = "Pesquisando: " + this.value;
  log.insertBefore(li, log.firstChild);
}, 1000));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>

<input id="search">
<hr>
<ul id="log"></ul>
```